# Generate response error in Swagger - .netCore Api

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-core, .net-core, swagger

For handling all errors I use ErrorHandlingMiddleware. Anywhere where I want I throw exception (my implementation exception) where I define type (enum) and message of errors.
My question is how can I generate this type of error in swagger, becaouse swagger know only about controller return type values. And swagger generate only response (200) bcs in methods is only return Ok();

```
[HttpPost("login")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Test(LoginRequest req)
{
    if (user.Banned)
    {
        throw new BadRequestHorseedoException(ErrorCode.BANNED, "User is banned");
    }

    return Ok();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`ProducesResponseType`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/action-return-types?view=aspnetcore-5.0) attribute on methods. Your code can look like:

```cs
[HttpPost("login")]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError)]
public async Task<IActionResult> Test(LoginRequest req)
```

Comment: I know about it but I have own ErrorResponse Class for all responses. And here I can only use StatusCodes Enum.

Comment: I can handle like this:
`[ProducesResponseType(200)]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(ErrorResponse), 400)]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(ErrorResponse), 401)]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(ErrorResponse), 500)]`

But its so ugly :D

Comment: Yes, it's messy verbose. Maybe look at conventions https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/advanced/conventions?view=aspnetcore-5.0